# Remove strange character from tokenization array

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, data-cleaning

I have a very dirty Pyspark dataframe, i.e. full of weird characters like:

- ɴɪᴄᴇ ᴏɴᴇ ᴀᴩᴩ
- பரமசிவம்
- and many others

I'm doing the data processing and cleaning (*tokenization*, *stopword removal*, ...) and this is my dataframe:

| content | score | label | classWeigth | words | filtered | terms_stemmed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| absolutely love d... | 5 | 1 | 0.48 | [absolutely, love... | [absolutely, love... | [absolut, love, d... |
| absolutely love t... | 5 | 1 | 0.48 | [absolutely, love... | [absolutely, love... | [absolut, love, g... |
| absolutely phenom... | 5 | 1 | 0.48 | [absolutely, phen... | [absolutely, phen... | [absolut, phenome... |
| absolutely shocki... | 1 | 0 | 0.52 | [absolutely, shoc... | [absolutely, shoc... | [absolut, shock, ... |
| accept the phone ... | 1 | 0 | 0.52 | [accept, the, pho... | [accept, phone, n... | [accept, phone, n... |

How can I access the `word` column and remove all weird characters, like the ones mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UDF.

```
>>> @udf('array<string>')
... def filter_udf(a):
...     from builtins import filter
...     return list(filter(lambda s: s.isascii(), a))
... 

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(['pyspark','பரமசிவம்'],)])
>>> df.select(filter_udf('_1')).show()
+--------------+
|filter_udf(_1)|
+--------------+
|     [pyspark]|
+--------------+
```